# Show that an elliptic curve is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography

> **[Theorem]** Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$, $q=p^n$ for some prime $p$. Then there exists positive integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $E \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}$ where $n_2 \mid n_1$.

I'm given an elliptic curve $E$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$, and using maple I was able to find the orders of elements in $E$:

1. Of course, Point at infinity has order $1$.
2. There are $24$ elements of order $5$.
3. There are $400$ elements of order $401$.
4. There are $9600$ elements of order $2005$.
5. Total number of elements of $E$ is $10025$.

Now, I want to find positive integers $n_1, n_2$ in the Theorem. I know that there is one sub-cyclic group of order $401$, so I suppose $n_1=10025$ and $n_2=401$? But I don't know if this is really true.

Comment: Anyway, if you know that  the total number of $\Bbb{F}_q$-rational points if $10025$ then you must have the equation $n_1n_2=10025$. Another general fact is that $n_2\mid q-1$, so telling us the value of $q$ would help.

Comment: Actually, given that $2005$ is square-free, and the piece that there are more than $5$ solutions to $[5]P=0$ leave only a single possibility: $n_2=5, n_1=2005$. The key items are: A) $n_2^2$ must be a factor of the total number, B) If for some prime $\ell$ there are more than $\ell-1$ elements of order $\ell$ then we must have $\ell\mid n_2$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen oh sorry, I forgot to consider that. Otherwise the total number of element wouldn't be $10025$. I think you are right. It's just about finding possible pair of $n_1$ and $n_2$. Since I'm not given a proof of the theorem, I was wondering if there is a proof using abstract algebra. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: By the theorem of invariant factors, each finite abelian group has a unique decomposition as $(\Bbb Z/d_1)\times(\Bbb Z/d_2)\times\dots\times(\Bbb Z/d_k)$, where $k\ge 1$ is the number of the cartesian parts, and the $d$-factors are respecting the chain division $d_1|d_2|\dots|d_k$. (Use $\oplus$ instead of $\times$ if it looks better.) In our case, since the total number of elements is $5^2\cdot 401$, we have only the chances ($k=1$, $d_1=5^2\cdot 401$) and ($k=2$, $d_1=5$ and divides $d_2=5\cdot 401$). Now we count the elements of order five...